# Объединение значений массива

Tags: php

Имеется массив типа

```
[0] => array(7) {
  ["rel_id_op"]  => string(1) "1"
  ["product_id"] => string(4) "1012"
  ["quantity"]   => string(1) "0"
  ["price"]      => string(8) "158.0000"
  ["option_id"]  => string(2) "15"
  ["relatedoptions_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["option_value_id"]   => string(4) "2417"
}
[1] => array(7) {
  ["rel_id_op"] => string(1) "1"
  ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1012"
  ["quantity"]  => string(1) "0"
  ["price"]     => string(8) "158.0000"
  ["option_id"] => string(2) "16"
  ["relatedoptions_id"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["option_value_id"]  => string(4) "2759"
}
```

подскажите как мне объединить элементы массива по полю `relatedoptions_id`, объединить если они одинаковые, хочу получить так с полями `option_id`

```
[0] => array(7) {
  ["rel_id_op"]  => string(1) "1"
  ["product_id"] => string(4) "1012"
  ["quantity"]   => string(1) "0"
  ["price"]      => string(8) "158.0000"
  ["option_id"]  => string(2) "15"
  ["option_id"]  => string(2) "16"
  ["relatedoptions_id"] =>  string(1) "1"
  ["option_value_id"]   =>  string(4) "2417"
  ["option_value_id"]  => string(4) "2759"
}
```

Или объединить выбор из БД, таблица имеет вид 
http://joxi.ru/brRDKejCQedaM2, как их обьеденить по relatedoptions_id, с выводом всех option_id и option_value_id?

Comment: что-то вид желаемого результата у вас какой то не корректный. у вас там получилось два поля `option_id` и пропал куда-то один `option_value_id`. уточните, чего хотите

Comment: Да, действительно случайно пропустил

Comment: Исправил конечный результать

Comment: ну тогда еще раз исправьте, как я уже написал, в массиве не может быть два элемента с одинаковым ключом.

Comment: Да я понимаю это, в этом и проблема я знаю как обьеденить в таком формате, даже если как-то переименовать похожие ключи, я думаю может лучше выбор с базы изменить

Comment: `'option_ids' => [15,16], option_value_ids' => [2417, 2759] ` ? или если они связаны то `options => [15 => 2417, 16 => 2759]` ?

Comment: options => [15 => 2417, 16 => 2759]